# php fatal error wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error on my website:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_settings() on a non-object in /home4/gabeweb/public_html/store/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-install.php on line 291
```

this is Line 291 :

```
foreach ( $section->get_settings() as $value ) {
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue? Can't get into the admin of my wordpress site due to this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a problem with your plugin.  If you rename the `woocommerce` folder within `wp-content/plugins/` then the plugin will be deactivated, allowing you to get into the admin area.